# My PyCharm start with /usr/bin/sh instead of /bin/bash in Linux Mint and not changing manually

Tags: bash, shell, pycharm, linux-mint

I have installed **PyCharm CE 2019.3** on **Linux Mint Tricia** and when I start PyCharm, the inbuilt terminal starts with */usr/bin/sh* when I type command *which bash* in it.

The default system interpreter in the PyCharm setting is also showing */usr/bin/python3.7* but I want to use */bin/python3.7*. The terminal shell path in PyCharm setting is showing */bin/sh* by default which looks correct and for cross check I changed it to */bin/bash* but the terminal shell is not changing.

I don't want to use */usr/bin/bash* and /usr/bin/python3 because I need to use pyinstaller which works well only with global Python3 interpreter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried different ways including different versions of PyCharm and Linux distros. The issue is occurring when I am installing PyCharm CE from software center in latest Ubuntu (19.04) and Linux Mint. The issue is not coming when I am installing the same in Ubuntu 18.04 but the best solution I have achieved is by installing the PyCharm CE using Jetbrains toolbox and the issue is not coming even in Linux Mint 19.3.  Hope, it may help someone. Thanks!